# How to include nullable objects and then ThenInclude another nullable object in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using jet brains Rider and Resharper gives an error when i dont declare objects like `Organization` as `nullable`.
[image]

Actually, it should be nullable, since i might not include it in the EFCore query.

Now I've set it to
`public Organization? Organization { get; set; }`

The problem I'm facing is this:
[image]

What is the best way to solve this warning? What is the best practice here?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17212

Comment: Post your code as *text*. The warning doesn't appear in the `Include` operations. The actual code is hidden by a popup

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay maybe not - these aren't DbSets and the actual warning is raised in the `Where` operator which is hidden by a popup. For all we know this may be a valid warning

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There's also a warning in `ThenInclude`.

Comment: All the more reason to post both code and warnings as text, not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is safe to ignore since the expression will be translated by EF core to an SQL Query, and won't be actually evaluated by the .NET runtime (so no `NullReferenceException` would be thrown).

So the `!` (null-forgiving) operator can be used to silence the warning as in

```cs
Where(g => g.Organization!. /* rest of the expression here*/ )
```